# Google Apps Script - Code Optimization for Google functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

Is there any possibility of reducing the runtime on these three parts of the function? The function itself runs fine, but these 3 parts add up to over a second. Wondering if there's a way to make less calls to SpreadSheetApp (by combining the getSheets and getRange somehow?), or if loading a json file from Google Drive can be quicker.

`var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];`

`function loadIconDictionary()`

`var currentCell = sheet.getRange(currentRow, columnMappings[col].sourceCol).getValue();`

Code and runtime below. The function just checks on edit if the cell entered is included in a dictionary, and if it does, it puts an image to the right of that cell. IconDictionary function loads a json file that contains the dictionary.

```
//Loads icon if a user fills in a class name
function userEdit(e) {
  console.time('myFunction');
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  console.timeEnd('myFunction');
  // Define the column mappings for your specific case
  var columnMappings = {
    1: { sourceCol: 1, targetCol: 2 },
    7: { sourceCol: 7, targetCol: 8 },
    13: { sourceCol: 13, targetCol: 14 }
  };

  // Check if the edited column is in the mappings
  if (columnMappings[col] && sheet != roster) {
    var currentRow = e.range.getRow();
    var targetCol = columnMappings[col].targetCol;
    console.time('myFunction2');
    if (Object.keys(ICON_DICTIONARY).length === 0) {
      ICON_DICTIONARY = loadIconDictionary(); // Load icon dictionary if not already loaded
    }
    console.timeEnd('myFunction2');
    console.time('myFunction3');
    try {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(currentRow, columnMappings[col].sourceCol).getValue();
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
    console.timeEnd('myFunction3');
    if (ICON_DICTIONARY.hasOwnProperty(currentCell)) {
      sheet.getRange(currentRow, targetCol).setValue('=IMAGE("' + ICON_DICTIONARY[currentCell] + '")');
    }
    else if (currentCell === "") {
      sheet.getRange(currentRow, targetCol).setValue('');
    }
  }
}

function loadIconDictionary() {
  var fileId = '1Qe_ST11nJIBnPGX_98N0Etd2iHiG70cd'; // Replace with the ID of your file

  // Get the file by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  if (file) {
    // Convert the blob to a string
    var fileContent = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();

    if (fileContent) {
      try {
        // Parse the content into a JavaScript object (assuming it's JSON)
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(fileContent);

        // Now 'parsedData' contains the content of the file
        return parsedData
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log('Error parsing file content: ' + e);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('File is empty.');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('File not found.');
  }
}
```

```
Oct 4, 2023, 1:08:24 AM Debug   myFunction: 436ms
Oct 4, 2023, 1:08:24 AM Debug   myFunction2: 406ms
Oct 4, 2023, 1:08:25 AM Debug   myFunction3: 357ms
```

Edit: Function for multiple cell edits at once:

```
//DO NOT CHANGE loadIconDictionary to getIconDictionary, onEdit does not have privileges for DriveApp!
function onEdit(e) { 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Roster");
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  // Define the column mappings for your specific case
  var columnMappings = {
    1: { sourceCol: 1, targetCol: 2 },
    7: { sourceCol: 7, targetCol: 8 },
    13: { sourceCol: 13, targetCol: 14 }
  };

  // Check if the edited column is in the mappings
  if (columnMappings[col] && sheet != SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Roster")) {
    var currentRow = e.range.getRow();
    var numRows = 12; // Number of rows to update
    var targetCol = columnMappings[col].targetCol;
    var valuesToSet = [];  
    if (Object.keys(ICON_DICTIONARY).length === 0) {
      ICON_DICTIONARY = getIconDictionary(); // Load icon dictionary if not already loaded
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(currentRow + i, columnMappings[col].sourceCol).getValue();
      var cellValue = '';

      if (ICON_DICTIONARY.hasOwnProperty(currentCell)) {
        cellValue = '=IMAGE("' + ICON_DICTIONARY[currentCell] + '")';
      }
      else if (currentCell != "" || currentCell === false) {
        cellValue = sheet.getRange(currentRow + i, columnMappings[col].targetCol).getValue();
      }

      valuesToSet.push([cellValue]);
    }

    // Set values in a single batch operation
    sheet.getRange(currentRow, targetCol, numRows, 1).setValues(valuesToSet);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delay in getting sheets/range is usually due to the bulk of the spreadsheet. Consider deleting empty rows, empty columns. Consider consolidating multiple sheets into one. Consider reducing redundant data
2. Instead of `getActive()` calls, try getting  the data directly from the event object. Event objects also provide edited row and column information in properties `rowStart`, `columnStart`:
3. Use JavaScript optimizations like strict mode, `const`s instead of `var`s, strict equality checks, [dry](/questions/tagged/dry), etc
4. Use `offset` instead of getting `getRange` on  sheet for current row and value.
5. Try using `PropertiesService` instead of Drive files to store JSON

```
/**
 *
 * Loads icon if a user fills in a class name
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function userEdit(e) {
  'use strict';
  console.time('myFunction');
  const edRange = e.range;
  const edSheet = edRange.getSheet();
  const edCol = edRange.columnStart;
  //const roster = e.source.getSheets()[0];//use getSheetByName, if you already know the sheet name
  //alternatively, use
  const rosterShName = 'roster';
  console.timeEnd('myFunction');
  // Define the column mappings for your specific case
  const columnMappings = {
    1: { targetCol: 2 },
    7: { targetCol: 8 },
    13: { targetCol: 14 },
  };

  // Check if the edited column is in the mappings
  if (columnMappings[edCol] && edSheet.getName() !== rosterShName) {
    const offset = columnMappings[edCol].targetCol - edCol;
    console.time('myFunction2');
    const ICON_DICTIONARY = loadIconDictionary(); // Load icon dictionary if not already loaded
    console.timeEnd('myFunction2');
    console.time('myFunction3');
    const currentCell = e.value;
    const targetRg = edRange.offset(0, offset);
    if (ICON_DICTIONARY.hasOwnProperty(currentCell)) {
      targetRg.setValue('=IMAGE("' + ICON_DICTIONARY[currentCell] + '")');
    } else if (currentCell === '') {
      targetRg.setValue('');
    }
    console.timeEnd('myFunction3');
  }
}

function loadIconDictionary() {
  const fileId = '1Qe_ST11nJIBnPGX_98N0Etd2iHiG70cd'; // Replace with the ID of your file

  // Get the file by ID
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  if (file) {
    // Convert the blob to a string
    const fileContent = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();

    if (fileContent) {
      try {
        // Parse the content into a JavaScript object (assuming it's JSON)
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(fileContent);

        // Now 'parsedData' contains the content of the file
        return parsedData;
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log('Error parsing file content: ' + e);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('File is empty.');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('File not found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can same principles be applied for #2 and #4 on a function that edits multiple cells at once? I have a similar function that checks several at a time, and have edited it under the main question.

Comment: I was not sure how to use currentCell in the manner you proposed when it's under a loop.

Comment: @user3245228 Use `getValues()` outside the loop and loop over the values. Don't `getRange` inside the loop

Comment: I'll give that a try. Two more things while you are helping me out; 1) how do you use PropertiesService? and 2) these functions are effectively just putting in =IMAGE(URL). Is there any place that I can upload these images to load them faster on the sheet?

Comment: @user3245228 1. [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+*PropertiesService*) 2. No(unless the image is put in a public cdn).